# Laravel ENV problem with the configuration

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, dotenv

I'm running a php-fpm and a nginx docker container with a shared volume (not bind to host).

For my php-fpm I have an `.env` file with specific VARS and I also set specific VARS at `docker run` runtime (non that overrides the file).

Both run under non-system/root users, `invoiceninja` and `nginx`, respectively, and have the same `uid` and `guid` even tho

When I try to visit the application url I get:

> There appears to be a problem with your configuration, please check your .env file.
> If you've run 'php artisan config:cache' you will need to run 'php artisan config:clear'

If I execute the suggestion:

```
'php artisan config:cache' you will need to run 'php artisan config:clear'
```

I get:

> (1/1) RuntimeException No application encryption key has been specified at EncryptionServiceProvider->key(array('name' => 'Invoice Ninja', 'debug' => true, 'env' => 'local', 'url' => 'http://black-pearl.local:8000', 'timezone' => 'UTC', 'locale' => 'en', 'fallback_locale' => 'en', 'key' => '', 'cipher' => '', 'log' => 'syslog', 'providers' => array('Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider', 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',

`php artisan tinker` reveals that there IS IN FACT a key using `env('APP_KEY')` and also at `config('app.key')`  and `cat < .env` also reveals the key

In my *docker-entrypoint* I see the following:

```
# usage: file_env VAR [DEFAULT]
#    ie: file_env 'XYZ_DB_PASSWORD' 'example'
# (will allow for "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD_FILE" to fill in the value of
#  "$XYZ_DB_PASSWORD" from a file, especially for Docker's secrets feature)
file_env() {
    local var="$1"
    local fileVar="${var}_FILE"
    local def="${2:-}"

    if [ "$(ie_gv ${var})" != ""  ] && [ "$(ie_gv ${fileVar})" != "" ]; then
        in_error "Both $var and $fileVar are set (but are exclusive)"
    fi

    local val="$def"
    if [ "$(ie_gv ${var})" != "" ]; then
        val=$(ie_gv ${var})
    elif [ "$(ie_gv ${fileVar})" != "" ]; then
        val=`cat $(ie_gv ${fileVar})`
    fi

    export "$var"="$val"
    unset "$fileVar"
}

# Initialize values that might be stored in a file
file_env 'APP_KEY'
file_env 'API_SECRET'
file_env 'CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY'
file_env 'DB_USERNAME'
file_env 'DB_HOST'
file_env 'DB_DATABASE'
file_env 'MAIL_DRIVER'
file_env 'APP_CIPHER'
file_env 'REQUIRE_HTTPS'
file_env 'MAIL_HOST'
file_env 'MAIL_PORT'
file_env 'MAIL_USERNAME'
file_env 'MAILGUN_SECRET'
file_env 'S3_KEY'
file_env 'S3_SECRET'

# Run Laravel stuff
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
php artisan optimize

exec docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

I'm assuming here that the logic is looking for a file related variable and declares it in memory.

Is this a permissions problem? The permissions are the same on both containers.

Comment: "No application encryption key has been specified" means you don't have your APP_KEY set inside .env file. Run `php artisan key:generate` to create one.

Comment: @lewis4u and there in lies the problem I DO in fact have a key present